# Shape attribute on android

Tags: android, shapedrawable

I am using a shape to do a background transparent for an android layout. My code is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#77FFFFFF"/>

</shape>
```

But the color that I obtain is very dark, how can I do much lighter or more white? I don´t understand 77 what it means, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

77 is the alpha of your colour, i.e. how opaque you want it to be. So you should increase it to get a 'darker' colour. The rest are your normal hexadecimal colour codes.
Edit: By the way, the alpha part is also in hex, so you can increase it all the way up to FF for a totally white background, or if you're not concerned with transparency, you can just remove those first two digits altogether.

Refer to:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

77 is alpha channel in hexadecimal system. FF (hex) or is the same 255 (dec) is opaque. 00 (hex) or is the same 0 (dec) is fully transparent. For example if you want to do color with 80% opacity, you need to calculate it: 255 / 100 * 80 = 204; 204 in hexadecimal system is CC;